# Why did the DAG file change in block 1080000?

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, mining-pools, dag

I'm [mining to dwarfpool](http://dwarfpool.com/eth/address?wallet=2cc043fc021fd7a2be4ddfa90d863688c9baec72&allpayouts=1), and all of sudden am getting this message on the account: "*DAG file changed in block 1080000*"

Does this mean that my DAG is out of sync and if yes, how do I resync it, tried just rebooting miners but doesn't seem to fix it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, 2x Rig, first is 3x 280x and second is 280x, 7950, 270x!

Comment: @NikhilM please avoid chats and discussion in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay found the answer on another forum. It just means the next phase of the DAG is happening soon, apparently this takes place every 30,000 blocks. It becomes bigger.

At the time of writing this question the block didn't exist yet as it was still in the 1070000's - [just one minute ago it happened](http://etherscan.io/block/1080000).

Answer (score 2):

#### DAG

If your miner sent bad shares, there is a high chance that you have a corrupted DAG file.

You need delete it and restart miner:

- DAG files in OSX and Linux are here: `~/.ethash`
- DAG files in Windows are here: `C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Ethash`

See the [pool FAQ](http://dwarfpool.com/faq/).

Comment: I saw this but it doesn't seem I am sending bad shares, as it's still generating the same amount as it was prior to this message appearing. 

I figured there'd be a message on individual 'bad shares' if that was the case?